# Count Number of Child Nodes without using Tag Name (XML)

Tags: xml, xml-parsing

I'm working on a generic ASP.NET control that can be reused when a user needs to perform a search. The underlying service will call a stored proc which will run a select on one of five or six different views. The sp then returns the results of the query as XML.

The problem that I have is that the stored proc can return [n] number of columns depending on the actual search being executed (See the two examples below). How would I determine the number of child nodes per record? Specifically, how would I check the number of children under the  elements?

```
XML Sample Number 1
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<NewDataSet>
<Table>
<ProjectContact>
<Id>1613</Id>
<ProjectNumber>216206</ProjectNumber>
<DisplayName>Scott Jones</DisplayName>
<IsProjectLead>true</IsProjectLead>
<ProjectNameLong>Facility Management</ProjectNameLong>
<Comment>Created from 1713</Comment>
<ScheduleNoteId>5</ScheduleNoteId>
<ScheduleComment>Travel/Work</ScheduleComment>
</ProjectContact>
</Table>
</NewDataSet>

XML Sample Number 2
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<NewDataSet>
<Table>
<DisplayName>David Wilson</DisplayName>
<Id>1691</Id>
<Department>Electrical Services</Department>
<OfficeName>Orlando</OfficeName>
</Table>
</NewDataSet>
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to return in the sample cases? The number of children of `Table`, i.e. `1` and `4`?

Comment: Yes. The number of child nodes under the "Table" element.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the XML API you use but and whether you parse the XML with white space preservation or not but in general there are several ways, one is XPath where you can simply use `count(*)` in the context of a `Table` element to find the number of child elements. Using DOM and assuming you don't preserve white space when loading you can also read out `.ChildNodes.Count` when you have selected a `Table` element. Using LINQ to XML you can use `.Elements().Count()` with a `Table` element as the context node.

Answer (score 0):

What would the JavaScript be then? My problem is that my knowledge is limited with the XML Dom and Dom. I'm having problems getting a reference to the first Table element and then grabbing the count of children.

```
function executeSearch(){

    var searchvalue = document.getElementById("test").value;
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
            xmlResponse = xhttp.responseXML;
            recordCount = xmlResponse.getElementsByTagName("Table").length;
            if (recordCount > 0) {

            }
      }
    };
    xhttp.open("POST", "../../webservices/SearchDatabase.ashx?mode=contact&searchvalue=" + searchvalue, true);
    xhttp.send();
}
```